# Why does NUnit ignore datapoints when using generics in a theory

Tags: generics, nunit, theory

I'm trying to make use of the [TheoryAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5.3), introduced in NUnit 2.5. Everything works fine as long as the arguments are of a defined type:

```
[Datapoint]
public double[,] Array2X2 = new double[,] { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };

[Theory]
public void TestForArbitraryArray(double[,] array)
{
  // ...
}
```

It does not work, when I use generics:

```
[Datapoint]
public double[,] Array2X2 = new double[,] { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };

[Theory]
public void TestForArbitraryArray<T>(T[,] array)
{
  // ...
}
```

NUnit gives a warning saying `No arguments were provided`. Why is that?

Comment: I reported this behavior as a bug to the NUnit developers (https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/537914) and Charlie Poole opened a discussion regarding this issue on nunit-discuss (https://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/6d16b06ec18ca19f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because Datapoints have to match Types with the DatapointAttribute. From the [NUnit help](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=datapoint&r=2.5.3) on Datapoints:

> When a Theory is loaded, NUnit creates arguments for each of its parameters by using any fields **of the same type** as the parameter annotated with the DatapointAttribute. In addition, elements of arrays of the required type annotated with the DatapointsAttribute are also used.